# Creating an Object (from one of our classes) through reading in increments of 5

Tags: java, javafx

So, I am trying to create this little quiz game where the questions are read from a file. I got the main outlook of the game (the skeleton) but I can't get it to read the questions from a file correctly.

The file, let's name it "questions", contains something along these lines:

```
What_is_2+2?
4
3
5
6
```

I want the first line to be the question and the next 4 the possible answers. The first answer, in this case 4, will always be the right answer.

The output is made via buttons, lines 2-5 are read and made into buttons and line 1 is the main name of the question.

Here is my code so far:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static  final Font FONT = Font.font(20);
    private SidePane sPane = new SidePane();
    private QuestionPane qpane = new QuestionPane();
    List<Question> intrebari = new ArrayList<>();
    int first = 0;

    private Parent createContent() throws IOException {
        HBox root = new HBox(50);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(50,50,50,50));
        nextQuestion();
        qpane.setQuestion(new Question("What is 2+2?","4","5","6","-1"));

        root.getChildren().addAll(qpane,sPane);
        return root;
    }

    private void nextQuestion() {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\IdeaProjects\\Lab5\\src\\sample\\a");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {

            // read line by line
            String line1,line2,line3,line4,line5;
            while (br.readLine()!=null){
             line1 = br.readLine();
             line2 = br.readLine();
             line3 = br.readLine();
             line4 = br.readLine();
             line5 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line1+" "+line2+" "+line3+" "+line4+" "+line5);
            Question question = new Question(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5);
            intrebari.add(question);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
    }

    private class SidePane extends  VBox{
        private int current = 1;
        public SidePane(){
            super(10);
            for(int i=15;i>0;i--)
            {
                Text text =new Text("Question " + i);
                text.setFill(i==current ? Color.BLACK : Color.GRAY);

                getChildren().add(text);
            }
        }
        public void selectNext() {
            if(current == 15){
                return;
            }

          Text text = (Text)getChildren().get(15 - current);
          text.setFill(Color.GRAY);
          current++;
          text = (Text)getChildren().get(15 - current);
          text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    private class QuestionPane extends VBox{

        private Text text = new Text();
        private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        private Question current;

        public QuestionPane(){
            super(20);

            text.setFont(FONT);

            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.setFont(FONT);
                btn.setPrefWidth(120);
                btn.setOnAction(event -> {
                    if(btn.getText().equals(current.getCorectAnswer())){

                        qpane.setQuestion(intrebari.get(first));
                        first++;
                        sPane.selectNext();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("da...bv");
                    }
                });
                buttons.add(btn);
                hBox.getChildren().add(btn);
            }

            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(text,hBox);
        }

        public void setQuestion(Question question){
            current = question;
            text.setText(question.name);

            Collections.shuffle(buttons);
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                buttons.get(i).setText(question.answers.get(i));  //getting answers from the question in order
            }
        }
    }

    private class Question{
        private String name;
        private List<String> answers;

       public Question(String name, String... answers)
       {
           this.name=name;
           this.answers= Arrays.asList(answers);
       }

       public String getCorectAnswer(){
           return answers.get(0);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the "nextQuestion()" method.

The question is how do I make it so the "Question" objects are created only every other 5 lines?

```java
private void nextQuestion() {
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\IdeaProjects\\Lab5\\src\\sample\\a");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {

        // read line by line
        String line1,line2,line3,line4,line5;
        while (br.readLine()!=null){
            line1 = br.readLine();
            line2 = br.readLine();
            line3 = br.readLine();
            line4 = br.readLine();
            line5 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line1+" "+line2+" "+line3+" "+line4+" "+line5);
            Question question = new Question(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5);
            intrebari.add(question);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the *a* file?
Where this file is placed?
What are you getting as output and what are you expecting?

Comment: THX, i forgot to mention those

Comment: the file contains the questions and their answers, the file is in a folder where the class was created, the output is on screen as a window with a big question on it and 4 buttons that represent the answers. currently in the "nextQuestion()" function i create an object on every line instead of creating it every other 5 lines

Comment: Have you added the solution to the question? Then it's not really a question anymore. Otherwise I'm not sure what exactly your problem here is. Are you trying to skip the 2nd, 4th, 6th, ... questions (=every other question)? If so why did you put those questions into that file in the first place? If you simply want to skip the first question in the file for whatever reason (maybe you shouldn't hardcode that one in the first place), why not simply remove the first question from the list or simply start with the question at index 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
while (br.readLine()!=null){
    line1 = br.readLine();
    line2 = br.readLine();
    line3 = br.readLine();
    line4 = br.readLine();
    line5 = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line1+" "+line2+" "+line3+" "+line4+" "+line5);
    Question question = new Question(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5);
    intrebari.add(question);
}
```

with

```
while ((line1=br.readLine())!=null){        
    line2 = br.readLine();
    line3 = br.readLine();
    line4 = br.readLine();
    line5 = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line1+" "+line2+" "+line3+" "+line4+" "+line5);
    Question question = new Question(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5);
    intrebari.add(question);
}
```

The problem with your code is that you are calling `br.readLine()` six times instead of five times.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `BufferedReader` class.
Basically it has a `readLine()` method that you can call to retrieve the next line in the file. I usually use it in a `while` loop.

Comment: Thx, i got it to read, the only thing i need now is to figure a way to create the obj(question) in increments of 5